# How to omit redundant nested object keys

Tags: json, typescript

Let's say I have some JSON object that's structured like this:

```
object = {
  id: 1
  attributes: {
    title: 'title',
    content: 'content'
  }
}
```

And let's say I have a type Page like so:

```
type Page = {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  content: string
}
```

Is there a way I can edit this type, such that it will automatically omit the 'attributes' key, allowing me to do the following:

```
page: Page = object;
// page.title == 'title' should be true
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: No. Typescript cannot guess at what you feel is redundant. You have to flatten the object to match whatever interface you want. You can write a general purpose object flattening function, but it can’t happen “automatically”

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, Typescript type annotations do not affect the exported code. That is, the output of tsc does not change if you declare everything to be of type "any" or leave types out altogether. The types are just a means of doing static analysis during compilation.

Comment: @rejdeboer Was `object` supposed to be a value or a type? The `"id"` prop in `Page` is a `string`, but `object` uses a number.

Comment: Your comments helped me realize that I shouldn't try to approach this with typescript, but it might be better to make some kind of custom constructor that will flatten these redundant fields (similar to what @bryan60 suggested). Thanks for the help!